# How can I acquire international prepaid credit cards for e-com checkout integration testing?

Tags: integration-testing

For integration tests of an e-commerce checkout process that includes the credit card payment gateway of a third party, I would like to acquire prepaid credit cards. Especially for fraud-prevention it's very hard to test the full process inclusively without having real cards.

I am located in Germany, where it's possible to buy these kinds of cards that come with a pre-charged amount of money (typically something like 25, 50, 100 Euros) in gas stations and small stores that also sell top-up mobile phone credit. These cards work well, but are not helpful for testing processes that include issuer-country fraud-prevention methods at the 3rd party.

I know that in the US there are gift Visa cards such as the [Walmart Visa Gift Card](https://www.walmartgift.com/wmgift), but it says they only work in the US, and not on the Internet.

Finding working cards seems to be pretty hard and the only idea I've had so far is asking friends in other countries or colleagues who go on vacation to look out for this type of card.

They should exist in a lot of countries, as long as credit card is a broadly accepted payment method there, and there are parts of the population who might not have a good credit history, as paying cash for a one-time credit card number eliminates that factor and enables them to buy stuff online.

I am looking for solutions of either how to acquire one of those cards from a country other than Germany, or alternative methods to integration test my checkout.

Comment: @Bharat please do not make minor edits that do not improve questions. All your edit did was introduce grammar mistakes into the question, and your edit summary did not give conclusive information why you made those. I've rolled back the changes.

Answer (score 2):

Hi it really depends on the Payment provider your website opted for.

For Example, we use Payment Express and PayWave as our payment service providers and they have dummy cards for Visa, Master, A.E for testing purpose.

Not sure, but might be useful for you [http://www.paymentexpress.com/Technical_Resources/Integrated_Eftpos/Eftpos_Test_Cards](http://www.paymentexpress.com/Technical_Resources/Integrated_Eftpos/Eftpos_Test_Cards/)

Comment: Asking for a dummy card has not occurred to me. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: The test numbers behind your link work for checking fraud prevention. When I say I allow Canada and I pick the CHF card, I get the correct error message from my payment provider. But if I use the CAD card, I get a _card is not valid_ error. So this is partly useful, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check below link, May be it will useful for you.

https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/vhelp/paypalmanager_help/credit_card_numbers.htm

Comment: None of those work for me I'm afraid. Good idea though.